# Eclipse Plugin or else for coding footnote

Tags: eclipse, ide, coding-style, comments, footnotes

I love the Manning In Action Series. One of appealing area is that the code listing inside the book always has a footnote where there is a detailed explanation by a reference number. See below the example:

[image: Footnote Example]

So I'm wondering if there is an Eclipse plugin or online blogging service that allows footnote taking in the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you'll get is the the eclipse "NotePad" plugin. It doesn't create footnotes directly, but rather just takes plaintext notes and puts them in the metadata. You'll find it at: http://eclipsenotepad.sourceforge.net/

Better, though, is to use eclipse's built-in indexing, and leave yourself

```
/* @TODO 1) take note of this notey note */
```

comments near important lines.

"But sleepynate", you may say, "that's madness! I don't have anything TODO there!"

While this is true, eclipse automatically indexes certain comment tags, like `@TODO` and `@FIXME`, and puts them in your "Tasks" window. (Window > Show View > Tasks if yours is currently hidden. You can then double-click any one of them to jump to that line. You can also arbitrarily add tasks from the Edit menu with whatever label you want, in any resource and location within your project.

Comment: Also, Eclipse has a bookmarks feature that does something similar.

Comment: Yea, I this is true. They all show up in the "annotations" section of the preferences :)

I personally like the @ annotations because you don't have to stop coding to add them.